# How do I include outlier points in the boxplot min and max range?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, outliers

[image]

For WT_C57BL6, the boxplot is reading the bottom points as outliers. I want the boxplot min range to be extended to those "outlier" points and see the different quartile and mean placement. I basically want the lower points to not be seen as outliers. How do I do that?

I am using the ggplot and geom_boxplot/geom_jitter function to create my figure.

Comment: Please share reproducible sample data, e.g., `dput(subset(your_data, Type == "WT_C57BL6"))`. And the code you're using to make the graph. But, in short, boxplots [have a commonly accepted definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot#Visualization), where the bottom of the lower whisker is the first quartile minus 1.5 times the interquartile range. If you look at the `?geom_boxplot` help page, you can see a lot of details about the standard definition and options for changing it. See especially the *Summary statistics* section. You could write your own version of `stat_boxplot`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points are plotted as "outliers", when they are 1.5 times the interquartile range (IQR) beyond the box. This can be adjusted with the `coef` parameter, which is 1.5 by default. Increasing it will include more points.

For example, compare

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), hp)) + geom_boxplot()
```

with

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), hp)) + geom_boxplot(coef = Inf)
```